# Switch vs ArrayList Java

Tags: java, performance, list, switch-statement

I have multiple conditions(almost 30) to check for:
So which option would be better:

1. Writing switch conditions for each case
2. Creating a private static List and then check if the list contains that element or not.

In later case, I have to create 3 lists having 10 elements each, and then if result is found in list 1, then my variable would be say a, if found in list 2, then say b.

Comment: Be more specific about what conditions you are checking.

Comment: Sounds like you need a map.

Comment: @nhouser9 conditions for checking: if foo1 then bar, foo2 then car, foo3 then tar, foo4 then car, so till foo30 and they can have bar, car, or tar, then i get some result (foo<n>) and i've to check if it's a bar,car or tar

Comment: You should probably use objects and polymorphism instead of either of the options you suggest in your question but without showing us your code I can't answer further.

Comment: @nhouser9 Indeed, a relatively large number of elements can be classified into  several groups, subclass or some enum tag can be applied here.

Comment: @LukeLee so show us the actual code and maybe we can provide that solution =]

Answer (score 1):

There are pros and cons of both the methods but I would recommend using switch statement because

- code will be readable and understandable to others.
- o(1) condition checking
- I am not sure how will the second option be useful if there are some new conditions proposed in future.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need `if` statements to check for the three conditions. Inside the `if`, you can then check if the element is present in a `HashMap`.